# Intel Wireless card not recognized on HP Zbook laptop

Tags: drivers, wireless, intel, iwlwifi, modprobe

I tried to install Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 on my new HP Zbook laptop, but I face a problem with the detection of the Intel Wireless card for Wifi.

Everything works fine except that the Intel Wireless card does not show up.
It is not a hardware problem because the Wireless card works perfectly on Windows 11.

The Wireless card model is : Intel(R) Wifi 6E AX211 160 Mhz
I tried to load the driver manually :

```
root@zbook-steph:~# modprobe iwlwifi

root@zbook-steph:~# lsmod | grep iwlwifi
iwlwifi 450560 0
cfg80211 974848 1 iwlwifi

[ 249.611893] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[ 249.612024] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[ 249.621717] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
```

The Wifi module loads in the kernel, I have no error messages, but the card still does not show up:

iw list

<empty>

I tried to disable all security features in the BIOS (Secure Boot, TPM, etc.), but this does not change anything. I think I'm missing something here, but I don't know what.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Hi, by some miracle, the Wifi adapter is now active. Don't know what has changed. However I still have a problem when Wifi is active is that after some time, the PC gets blocked. I suspect an IRQ / memory conflict. I  get some alerts in the log :

Comment: warning: `iwconfig' uses wireless extensions which will stop working for Wi-Fi 7 hardware; use nl80211

Comment: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE) is beyond end of object (length 0x4) (20230331/exoparg2-393)

Comment: 7.034777] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination

Comment: I tried to reconfigure the interface using iw instead of iwconfig as suggested in some blogs

Comment: root@zbook-steph:/var/log# iw dev wlp0s20f3 connect Livebox-B600
command failed: Input/output error (-5)

Comment: And nice errors in dmesg :

Comment: [  965.745139] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
[  966.234471] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
[  966.391076] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_UMAC_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x20
[  966.391125] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_LMAC2_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x1f
[  966.391239] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0: 0x90
[  966.391292] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: CNVI_SCU_SEQ_DATA_DW9: 0x0
[  966.392520] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: RFIm is deactivated, reason = 4
[ 1033.803073] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.